# How to handle image/gif type response on client side using GWT

Tags: jsp, gwt

I have a question about how to handle image/gif type response on client side, any suggestion will be great.
There is a service which responds for retrieving image (only one each time at the moment) from database. The code is something like,

```
    JDBC Connection
    Construct MYSQL query. 
    Execute query
    If has ResultSet, retrieve first one {
    //save image into Blob image, “img” is the only entity in the image table.
    image = rs.getBlob("img"); 
} 

    response.setContentType("image/gif");   //set response type
    InputStream in = image.getBinaryStream();   //output Blob image to InputStream
    int bufferSize = 1024;  //buffer size
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];       //initial buffer
    int length =0;
    //read length data from inputstream and store into buffer   
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);       //write into ServletOutputStream 
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush(); //write out
```

The code on client side

```
    ....
    imgform.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "serviceexample/ImgRetrieve"); 
    ....
    ClickListener {
        OnClick, then imgform.submit();
    }


    formHandler {

    onSubmit, form validation

    onSubmitComplete
        ??????? //handle response, and display image
            **Here is my question, i had tried 
            Image img = new Image(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"serviceexample/ImgRetrieve");
            mg.setSize("300", "300");
            imgpanel.add(img);
            but i only got a non-displayed image with 300X300 size.**
    }
```

So, how should i handle the responde in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very obscure... I see a combination of old school HTML forms/submit and GWT code.

A regular GWT application only needs to have an Image widget put somewhere in your UI that referes to the url of the image service you described.

How or when to show the image is up to you.
But all you need to do to get the Image shown in you browser is to do

```
Image img = new Image( [url to image service] );
panel.add( img );
```

where panel is some panel that is already showing.

If you wish to wait for showing the image until the user clicks on some button then do this:

```
button.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick( ClickEvent e ) {
    Image img = new Image( [url to image service] );
    panel.add( img );
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe I did not explain my question correctly. Actually, my application is to create a registered user login interface. Registered user has photo stored in DB (uploaded when registration ), and once user login successfully, his/her photo will be retrieved from DB and displayed, so using the combination of form submit and GWT is the only solution I have found, just wondering if there are any other techniques can be used in this case, as this is my fist GWT application.

Comment: I had tried to display image by using<pre>Image img = new Image( “http://www.google.com/intl/en_AL/images/logo.gif” );</pre>,which is working as expected.Since my image is stored in ServletOutputStream,I tried to use<pre>Image img = new Image (GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "serviceexample/ImgRetrieve"); </pre>But image is not displayed.

Comment: find a post at GWT forum,
http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/92c9e8ac269c0e8e/21c62f16b9a27c8a?lnk=gst&q=create+blob